# Plotting Legendre Polynomials - Getting different results for own method

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, approximation, polynomials, function-approximation

I'm trying to plot the legendre polynomials, defined as:

```
P0(x) = 1
P1(x) = x
Pn+1(x) = ((2n+1)/(n+1)) * x * Pn(x) - (n / (n+1)) * Pn-1(x)
```

I've done it the easy slow way, and I've done it the direct, a little more complicated way. Both result in a similar figure, however, not quite the same. The Amplitudes are different. Here is the code with the respect figure (Notice that I adjust the subscript n+1 of the definition to n):

```
xi = linspace(-1,1,500);
n = 10;
```

Method 1:

```
Pn = cell(n+1,1);
Pn{1} = @ (x) 1;
Pn{2} = @ (x) x;
for i=3:(n+1)
    Pn{i} = @ (x) ((2*(i-1)+1)/(i)).*x.*Pn{i-1}(x) - ((i-1)/i) .* Pn{i-2}(x);
end
plot(xi,Pn{1}(xi),'--r',xi,Pn{2}(xi),'--g',xi,Pn{3}(xi),'--b',...
    xi,Pn{4}(xi),'--m',xi,Pn{5}(xi),'--c',xi,Pn{6}(xi),'--k');
legend('P0','P1','P2','P3','P4','P5');
```

Figure 1:

[image: Method 1]

Method 2:

```
%Notice here that the results of Pj get stored into YI(j+1)
YI = zeros(length(xi),6);
YI(:,1) = ones(size(xi))';
YI(:,2) = xi';
for i=3:6;
    Pn1 = 1;
    Pn2 = xi;
    for j=2:(i-1) 
        Pn3 = ((2*(j-1)+1)/j) .* xi .* Pn2 - ((j-1) / j) .* Pn1;
        Pn1 = Pn2;
        Pn2 = Pn3;
    end
    YI(:,i) = Pn3';
end
figure('Name','direct method');
plot(xi,YI(:,1)','--r',xi, YI(:,2)', '--g', xi, YI(:,3)', '--b', ...
    xi,YI(:,4)','--m', xi,YI(:,5)', '--c', xi,YI(:,6)', '--k');
```

Figure 2:

[image: Method 2]

This is weird, to say the least. For method 1 I'm calculating all the polynomials up to P11, but only utilizing the first 6 to plot. Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: And remember! DO NOT use i and j as variable names in Matlab. They are the complex unit and you may screw up the complex mathematics of Matlab. Use ii, jj or any other variable name you want, but no i or j. You make Matlab slower (it neds to sort out variable names more complexly) and destroy the math in any built in function using complex numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method#2 can be made much simpler:

```
X = linspace(-1,1,500); X = X(:);
N = 10;

Y = zeros(numel(X),N);
Y(:,1) = 1;
Y(:,2) = X;
for n=1:(N-1)
    Y(:,n+2) = ((2*n+1) .* X .* Y(:,n+1) - n .* Y(:,n)) / (n+1);
end

figure, plot(X, Y(:,1:6))
legend(num2str((1:6)'-1,'P_%d(x)'))
xlabel('x'), ylabel('P_n(x)'), title('Legendre Polynomials')
```

[image: legendre_polynomials]

This is equivalent to [the plot shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Legendrepolynomials6.svg) on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).

---

### EDIT:

I had an off-by-one bug in the array indexing; MATLAB uses 1-based indexing, but the formula is defined in a 0-based manner. It is fixed now, sorry for the confusion ;)

[image: formula]

To confirm `P(n=2,x=0)` should be `-1/2`:

```
>> interp1(X, Y(:,3), 0)
ans =
   -0.5000
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification, but that doesn't really answer my question. What is exactly wrong with my method?

Comment: I've went through the approach with a test value of 0, inputting it into P2. P2(t) is defined as 3/2 * t^2 - 1/2. My approach gives -0.5, which is correct, and yours does -2/3, which is obviously not according to above definition. However, all the legendre polynomials look like your curve. I am really confused now, I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: @BananaCode: the problem is with the second for-loop, it should be `for j=3:i` instead of `for j=2:(i-1)`. As you may have noticed now, your code is computing `P_n` by repeatedly starting from `P_0` going all the way up... Thanks to [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) method, you dont have to compute those values over and over again, just reuse the computation from the previous (two) iteration

Comment: But your values are wrong according to the definition above! Like I said, take P2 for instance. P2(0) should equal -0.5 but yours does -2/3. I have no doubt that you are correct, but this issue is confusing me.

Comment: Ok now I'm sure. You have your indexes wrong @Amro. My method 1 was wrong, and method 2 correct. But thanks for your simpler version!

Comment: @BananaCode: oh you are absolutely right! The code is now fixed.